# Can two events be independent if neither affects the other, but both are affected by a third factor?

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Example: The probabilities of a successful vegetable harvest from two gardens on opposite sides of town could be thought of as independent because neither garden affects the other one. Yet both are  affected by shared climatic/weather conditions, in which case the events are at least correlated.

Comment: Ask yourself... whether the weather really matters if its constant (same) over the 2 gardens at any given time? And 2 events are considered dependent if **only** one affects the other or both affect each other

Comment: This is my instinct too. I'm asking because as a Stats teacher I get a lot of students claiming that the assumption of independence (needed to multiply probabilities together, for example) is violated if there is something that acts on both probabilities. E.g. the probabilities of two people buying items from a shop are affected by a promotion, therefore those probabilities are not independent...

Comment: @UnexpectedConfusion may be right that your weather example has some difficulties. However, if $X$ and $Y$ processes are both affected by some kind of error $e,$ then $X$ and $Y$ may be correlated. Consider the following simulation in R: `set.seed(2021); e = rnorm(100, 0, 30);
x = rnorm(100, 50, 5)+e; y = rnorm(100, 60, 1)+e;  cor(x,y)` returns
$0.9853718.$ // Your question seems a bit vague. Does this simulation fit what you have in mind?

Comment: Yeah I get the idea about the correlation of both variables when each is affected by an external factor (error). My question is whether that correlation means they can no longer be considered independent of each other for the purposes of calculating probabilities for combinations of outcomes.

Comment: I'd say a correlation $r_{x,y} \approx 0.99$ pretty much ends the discussion of any kind of independence, for whatever purpose.